# Search MySQL database if entry found and display it, if not, add it

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, sql-insert

I'm a newbie to PHP and MySQL. I know there are lots of similar threads but I just can't seem to find one with my issue.

At the moment I have a table named 'movies' in my database. I have a search form to search for movies in that table. I'm using the code below to get the information from my database and display it.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE titleid='$urlid'";
$result = $con->query($query);
if( !$result ) {
die('Query failed!<br>'.$con->error);
}
if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {

}
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['title']; //this is not all of the columns just an example
}
```

What I want to do is:
If $urlid does not match 'titleid' then I want to add it to the database. At the moment I'm using the code below to add an entry:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO movies (id, aka, ratio, budget, cast, fullcast, linkcast, castcharacter, linkcastcharacter, company, linkcompany, description, directors, linkdirectors, genre, mpaa, synopsis, poster, rating, releasedate, runtime, sound, officialsites, tagline, title, trailerlink, titleid, year)
VALUES (NULL, '$aka', '$ratio', '$budget', '$cast', '$fullcast', '$linkcast', '$castcharacter', '$linkcastcharacter', '$company', '$linkcompany', '$description', '$directors', '$linkdirectors', '$genre', '$mpaa', '$synopsis', '$poster', '$rating', '$releasedate', '$runtime', '$sound', '$officialsites', '$tagline', '$title', '$trailerlink', '$urlid')";


mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

How could I combine them so if the record does not exist it adds it and then displays the information it has added?

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can insert and then select again, like this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE titleid='$urlid'";
$result = $con->query($query);
if( !$result ) {
    die('Query failed!<br>'.$con->error);
}
if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
    $insert_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO movies (id, aka, ratio, budget, cast, fullcast, linkcast, castcharacter, linkcastcharacter, company, linkcompany, description, directors, linkdirectors, genre, mpaa, synopsis, poster, rating, releasedate, runtime, sound, officialsites, tagline, title, trailerlink, titleid, year)
    VALUES (NULL, '$aka', '$ratio', '$budget', '$cast', '$fullcast', '$linkcast', '$castcharacter', '$linkcastcharacter', '$company', '$linkcompany', '$description', '$directors', '$linkdirectors', '$genre', '$mpaa', '$synopsis', '$poster', '$rating', '$releasedate', '$runtime', '$sound', '$officialsites', '$tagline', '$title', '$trailerlink', '$urlid')";
    mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);

    $result = $con->query($query);
    if( !$result ) {
        die('Query failed!<br>'.$con->error);
    }   
}
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['title']; //this is not all of the columns just an example
}
```

Also, I noticed that your INSERT statement may not be correct. Missing $year in values part.

Comment: Got down-voted without comment? Did my code not work, has issue?

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks to nawed.

What im struggling with now is counting how many times the page has been viewed. I have added the column 'views' to my table 'movies'

how can i increment + 1 each time the page is viewed using the above code?

I have tried 

    $updateviews = "INSERT INTO `movies` SET views=1 WHERE id=$id
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1 ;";
    mysqli_query($con, $updateviews);

But it does nothing.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is triggered only if row/data/record already exists. In your code the INSERT was executed because there was no record. This means the DUPLICATE never happens, hence the UPDATE never happens. Regardless the record already exists or you just inserted... execute an UPDATE query before starting the loop. Just execute a UPDATE statement and set views=views+1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE titleid='$urlid'";
$result = $con->query($query);
if( !$result ) {
die('Query failed!<br>'.$con->error);
}
if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
    $addQuery = "*your query here*";
    $con->query($query);
    echo "Movie added."
} else {
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['title']; //this is not all of the columns just an example
}
}
```

This will add it if there are no rows and otherwise show the results.

Comment: OP wants to combine, not do either. OP wants to add if missing and still show .. either from existing or from added.

Answer (score 0):

Only a supplement:
If your values are same order as in the 'movies' table, then you can use the shortest way:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO movies VALUES (
            NULL, '$aka', '$ratio', '$budget', '$cast', '$fullcast', '$linkcast', '$castcharacter', '$linkcastcharacter', '$company',
           '$linkcompany', '$description', '$directors', '$linkdirectors', '$genre', '$mpaa', '$synopsis', '$poster', '$rating',
           '$releasedate', '$runtime', '$sound', '$officialsites', '$tagline', '$title', '$trailerlink', '$urlid')";

mysqli_query($con, $query);
```